# Can VLCJ play reverse?

Tags: reverse, playback, vlcj

I am writing a custom video player in java using VLCJ and I need to be able to play video in reverse. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "no".

Neither vlcj nor VLC can play video in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

By constantly setting the time in reverse sequence, it can appear that the video is playing in reverse.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class SamplePlayer extends JFrame {

    long ttt;
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer ePlayer;

    public SamplePlayer() {
        String vlcPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC";

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), vlcPath);
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent playerComp = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        playerComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(playerComp);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        ePlayer = playerComp.getMediaPlayer();
        ePlayer.prepareMedia("video.mp4");

        ePlayer.play();

        java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ePlayer.pause();
                playReverse();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private void playReverse() {
        ttt = ePlayer.getLength();

        java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ttt -= 5;
                if (ttt < 1) {
                    cancel();
                }
                ePlayer.setTime(ttt);
            }
        }, 1000, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SamplePlayer();
    }
}
```